# jquery new slider image loading

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, slider

I build a jquery image slider and i want to enhance it , my problem is :
1.slide show begins before images are loaded
any advice for this and for enshancing this slider?
[Link](http://alhajj-lb.com/index.html)

Comment: Start your slider with `$(window).on('load',function() {...});` instead of `$(document).ready(function() {...});`

Comment: thank you , if you see that the images are loaded after each other and then the animation begins why?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand what you're trying to ask in your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know of 2 plugins that might help:

> 1) [ahpi.imgload.js](https://github.com/peol/jquery.imgloaded/blob/master/ahpi.imgload.js) replaces jQuery's .load() event with a special event that will fire regardless if image is cached.
>
> 2) [imagesloaded](https://github.com/desandro/imagesloaded) "A jQuery plugin that triggers a callback after all the selected/child images have been loaded. Because you can't do .load() on cached images."

Answer (score 0):

one option is that you can preload the images using the JS Image object.

```
function preloader(imageUrl)  { 
   heavyImage = new Image();  
   heavyImage.src = imageUrl;
}
```

use a function like this for all the images you want preloaded

Comment: where i call this function can you give a small example please